# For cycle with random indexes

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I'm writing a simple script where, given 4 integers in an list:

```
list = [ 10 , 20 , 30 , 40 ]
```

I iterate through all of them and in each cycle, I change the number being processed. One example would be to change number 10 to **any** other number I please (it could even be a result of a randint()). However, the processing of the number is not important here, but the way I iterate through the list.

A simple approach for the iteration would be to use a **for cycle**:

```
for i in list:
```

or

```
for x in range(3):
    print(list[x])
```

However, the problem I'm trying to solve is one I don't know if it's possible in python.

I want to iterate through all numbers of the list and when I modify the last number (N), I want to start the for cycle again, but in a different sequence.

Example (with indexes):

```
# first 4 cycles
order = 0 - 1 - 2 - 3

# second 4 cycles
order = 0 - 2 - 3 - 1

# third 4 cycles
order = 2 - 1 - 0 - 3

(...)
```

This means that integers would be processed int the following example order:

```
# first 4 cycles
order = 10 - 20 - 30 - 40

# second 4 cycles
order = 10 - 30 - 40 - 20

# third 4 cycles
order = 20 - 30 - 10 - 40

(...)
```

Note that in 4 consecutive cycles (N), there can be **no** repetition of an index, and thus, all numbers must be processed when the for cycle ends.

Is there any library that would help me? What would be the best approach for this?

Comment: "example: number 10 would become 11" why would it? The next item is 20 in the list. "for string in list:" they're integers.

Comment: The "why I'm modifying the numbers" is not the problem here. I explained the problem above. Yes, I wrote string by mistake, but it wouldn't change anything of the for cycle.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why there's 11 as coming after 10, when 11 isn't even in the list. It detracts from understanding if we're hitting these things; don't forget that everyone looking at this is doing it for free, so these basic issues really increase the chance people just give up.

Comment: I believe it's clear now, after the edit.

Comment: Did you want all possible combinations of the list or only 4 (per the answers below)?

Comment: Well, I do want all possible combinations, but I believe that, by using **random.shuffle** or the **np.random.permutation** (answers below), eventually, I will have used all possible permutations of indexes. But do you know a way to guarantee that I make all possible combinations?

Comment: @imll Yes I do. Just posted the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `random.shuffle` to shuffle a list in-place.

```
import random

list = [10, 20, 30, 40]
for i in range(5):
    random.shuffle(list)
    print('Cycle:')
    for x in list:
        print(x)
```

Gives:

```
Cycle:
40
30
10
20
Cycle:
10
40
30
20
Cycle:
20
10
30
40
Cycle:
30
40
20
10
Cycle:
40
10
20
30
```

This will change the order of the original list, so if you want to preserve that you should make a copy of it:

```
import random

list = [10, 20, 30, 40]

scratch_list = list[:] # shallow copy the list
for i in range(5):
    random.shuffle(scratch_list)
    print('Cycle:')
    for x in scratch_list:
        print(x)

# original list is still 10, 20, 30, 40
# scratch list is in random order
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [numpy.random.permutation](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html)

for example if you want to traverse the list 4 times and each time in different order you can use the following code

```python
import numpy as np
your_list = [10, 20, 30, 40]
for i in range(4):
  for j in np.random.permutation(len(your_list)):
    print(your_list[j], end=' -- ')
  print()
```

that would give you the following results

`40 -- 10 -- 20 -- 30 -- 
 30 -- 10 -- 40 -- 20 -- 
 30 -- 10 -- 20 -- 40 -- 
 40 -- 20 -- 30 -- 10 --`

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments by OP, a way to get all possible combinations of this list is as follows (using itertools):

```
from itertools import permutations

temp_list = [ 10 , 20 , 30 , 40 ]

[*permutations(temp_list)]
```

The output is as follows:

```
[(10, 20, 30, 40),
(10, 20, 40, 30),
 (10, 30, 20, 40),
 (10, 30, 40, 20),
 (10, 40, 20, 30),
 (10, 40, 30, 20),
 (20, 10, 30, 40),
 (20, 10, 40, 30),
 (20, 30, 10, 40),
 (20, 30, 40, 10),
 (20, 40, 10, 30),
 (20, 40, 30, 10),
 (30, 10, 20, 40),
 (30, 10, 40, 20),
 (30, 20, 10, 40),
 (30, 20, 40, 10),
 (30, 40, 10, 20),
 (30, 40, 20, 10),
 (40, 10, 20, 30),
 (40, 10, 30, 20),
 (40, 20, 10, 30),
 (40, 20, 30, 10),
 (40, 30, 10, 20),
 (40, 30, 20, 10)]
```